# iOS -AutoLayout constraint set active be crash in second time

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I want to achieve a function that when I click the buttons ,the image will move between two button

I set a constraint between image and button2 (centerX,which text with 222)  At the same time I set a constraint with button1（centerX,which text with 11） too and set the priority with 950 then I drag them to the `viewcontroller`

This is the constraint in my storyboard
[image]

This is my code to control the constraint

```
if NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1 {

            self.kidLeftCenterConstrait.active = isLeft
            self.kidRightCenterConstrait.active = !isLeft
            UIView.animateWithDuration(kAnimationDuration, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
          })

       } else {
            let constraintToRemove = isLeft ? self.kidRightCenterConstrait : self.kidLeftCenterConstrait
            let constriaintToUse = isLeft ? self.kidLeftCenterConstrait : self.kidRightCenterConstrait
            self.douBi.superview!.removeConstraint(constraintToRemove)
            self.douBi.superview!.removeConstraint(constriaintToUse)
            self.douBi.superview!.addConstraint(constriaintToUse)
            UIView.animateWithDuration(kAnimationDuration, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
      })
 }
```

After run in iphone 
  I click the button1 the image move to the 11 ,then i click the button2 ,The application is cash in `self.kidRightCenterConstrait.active = !isLeft`

console log is `fatal error:unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't use `removeConstraint` and `addConstraint`?

Comment: I have tried ,crashed in `kidRightCenterConstrait ` get nil

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It appears the constraint get released. You might try to strongly retain your constraints:

```
@IBOutlet var kidLeftCenterConstrait: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var kidRightCenterConstrait: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Anyway beware possible retain cycles. Check that your ViewController goes away when it's time has come.

I usually do this kind of animations managing the involved constraints all in code.

Comment: You would think this would be mentioned in the documentation.